# Updating CHM files

Tags: chm

My new client has his database schema as CHM file. As part of a release, we are supposed to update the CHM files.

Any idea as to how to update the CHM file?

**EDIT**

I am just asking for the tools which you can use to edit the CHM files. Microsoft does provide one [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=00535334-c8a6-452f-9aa0-d597d16580cc&displaylang=en). However, that one is not compatible with Windows Vista which is my current operating system.

Comment: You are mixing asking a technical question and asking other people to do your job for free, which isn't ethical. I think you should at least edit your question. Of course, instead you could just google up an answer to your question.

Comment: @vtest: Edited to make it clear. But I respectfully disagree with your comment of "asking other people to do my job for free". I was asking for an idea. I did not upload the CHM file (which you cannot do btw) and ask people to email me the resulting file. By extension, here is a question posted in SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497000/. Would you classify that too as asking people for doing the job for free? I guess No. I suspect it is the the wording that "My new client..." put you off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first extract the CHM file, then edit the html files, and do the repackage using `hhc` compiler at last.

Comment: @谢继雷: Thanks! How can I extract the CHM file? **EDIT** No problems, got a way here - http://techie-buzz.com/softwares/extract-html-from-chm-files.html

Comment: @Kanini http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help#Extracting_to_HTML

Comment: I have written a `unchm` some years ago, but I'm not sure if it works any more... http://trac.bodz.net/projects/bodz/browser/uni/xjl-coolchm/unchm  It's based on a modified version of `Archive::CHM` from `CPAN`. Write it your own if my `unchm` doesn't work.

Comment: Duh! Not necessary of any tools at all. The command hh.exe -decompile <PathWhereToStoreExtractedFile> <PathofCHMFile>

Comment: @Daniel Beck: +1 as Great Minds Think Alike :-) I found out from there only, just that my screen did not refresh before I wrote the above comment.

Comment: Umm.. `hh.exe` doesn't work in Linux, though, that's very convenient seems like I wrote too much codes. *_*

Comment: chmlib works in Linux and has a CLI tool called extract_chmLib.